# grpc server ruby with TLS/SSL

Tags: ruby, ssl, grpc

I am trying to implement a secure gRPC TLS connection between a ruby client and a ruby server.  I am unable to figure out how to configure the server to use the secure connection.

In production, our server is implemented in Go.  However, we have been unable to connect to it from ruby by anything other than an insecure connection.  I have been tasked with creating a reference TLS connection to show a secure connection from a ruby client will work.

I have the grpc quickstart example greeter working for ruby as an insecure connection.

In the [gRPC authentication documentation](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/) the Go example replaces this

```
s := grpc.NewServer()
```

with this

```
creds, _ := credentials.NewServerTLSFromFile(certFile, keyFile)
s := grpc.NewServer(grpc.Creds(creds))
```

for ruby there is this in the quickstart greeter app

```
s = GRPC::RpcServer.new
```

but I have been unable to find how to create a secure server.

The requirements include that we must have the server validate the client's public key as trusted in order to allow access to the server.  (The client will also need to trust the server's public key to validate the server.)

Comment: I've not used Ruby w/ gRPC but am familiar with the Golang SDK. See here for what appears to be a Ruby gRPC server w/ TLS: https://developers.google.com/maps-booking/legacy/booking-server-code-samples/gRPC-v0-legacy/partner-api-ruby

Comment: Your question is slightly unclear. It would be useful for you to get the Ruby client working with the Golang server so that you know that your certs and a client and server are working.

Comment: @DazWilkin yes but right now ruby is more accessible and familiar so I am trying to get that step working.  The team I am working with said they want to see the ruby client use a TLS gRPC call to anything for right now.

Comment: @DazWilkin That looks to be an answer.  If you put your comment as an answer, I will accept it and give you the reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used Ruby w/ gRPC but am familiar with the Golang SDK.

See here for what appears to be a Ruby gRPC server w/ TLS:

https://developers.google.com/maps-booking/legacy/booking-server-code-samples/gRPC-v0-legacy/partner-api-ruby